# Выполнение AJAX запроса

Tags: ajax, href

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы этот код работал не для всех ссылок, а только для ссылок находящихся в определенном div'е.

```
<script>
    $("a").click(function () {
        var handler = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: handler,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {

                $(".row").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

На данный момент тот код действует для всех ссылок. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы работало только для ссылок с определенным id или находящихся в определенном div'е. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну например вот так:

```
$("#your_div_name a").click(function(){ трам-пам-пам }
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery selector part 4 (c) Habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/51717/)
например так:

```
<div class='cls' id='some_id'>
    <a class='ajax' ...>link text</a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('a.ajax')...
    $('div.cls a.ajax')..
    $('div#some_id a.ajax')..
    $('div#some_id.cls a.ajax')..
    // и еще целая куча вариантов селекторов,
    // которые сводятся к одному и тому же смыслу
</script>
```